# React state update and display new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

I am trying to update a state value and display that updated value in an input field, but nothing seems to work for me.

I have been going through various articles and answers but none of the ways seem to work for me, possibly I am doing something wrong.

```
const AnswerDetailOptions = ({ options, className, answer_id, last_review_details }) => {
  const [reviewNoteDisplay, setReviewNoteDisplay] = useState(last_review_details.note)
  const [reviewNoteTimeStamp, setReviewNoteTimeStamp] = useState(last_review_details.date_time)

  useEffect(() => {
    // test
  }, [reviewNoteDisplay])

  const submitReview = async () => {
    const payload = {
      note: reviewNote,
      answer_id
    }

    const response = await submitNewReview(payload)
    //console.log(response)

    if (response.status === 201) {
      toast.success('Review saved successfully')

      setReviewNoteDisplay(() => return response.data.data.note)
      setReviewNoteTimeStamp(() => return response.data.data.date_time)

      closeCreateReviewDialog()
    } else {
      toast.error('Failed to save review')
    }
  }
```

Render:

```
{
        reviewNoteTimeStamp ? 
          <>
            <EditableText 
              multiline="true"
              placeholder="Write a review..."
              defaultValue={reviewNoteDisplay}
              confirmOnEnterKey="true"
              onChange={(new_value) => setReviewNoteDisplay(new_value)}
              onConfirm={editReview}
            />
            <p className={classNames(styles.node, styles.reviewTimeStamp)}>{ format(new Date(reviewNoteTimeStamp), 'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a') }</p>
            <Button onClick={() => setShowReviewHistory(true)}>Review History</Button>
          </> :
          <>
            <p>No reviews added</p>
          </>
      }
```

I am trying to get the new value of `reviewNoteDisplay` and `reviewNoteTimeStamp` but I keep geting the old value.

Comment: did you try it like this: `setReviewNoteDisplay(response.data.data.note)`?

Comment: yes. I did but nothing works.

Comment: where is the input field? i can't see it in your code example.

Comment: `setReviewNoteDisplay(() => return response.data.data.note)` is invalid code, use `setReviewNoteDisplay(() => response.data.data.note)` or `setReviewNoteDisplay(response.data.data.note)`

Comment: @TheWuif updated question with input field

Comment: @TheWuif I have tried all of the above combinations

Comment: your are setting `defaultValue={reviewNoteDisplay}` this will only update if the element is newly created. ill try to post a solution

Comment: How else can we show the changed value in the edit box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input needs to control the input, use `value` and not `defaultValue` here:

```
<EditableText 
 multiline="true"
 placeholder="Write a review..."
 value={reviewNoteDisplay}
 confirmOnEnterKey="true"
 onChange={(new_value) => setReviewNoteDisplay(new_value)}
 onConfirm={editReview}
/>
```

i don't know the EditableText component, but if `onChange` isn't fired on each key hit, you may also need to add:

```
onKeyUp={(e) => setReviewNoteDisplay(e.target.value)}
```

or something like this.

Comment: You were right. It should have been a controlled component. It works now. Thanks a ton.